# loading data to store but no data visible in grid

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http, extjs

So I load json to the store but no data visible in grid. What am I doing wrong? Here is the grid:

```
            {
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                title: 'Clients List',

                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

                    model: 'app.model.modelClients',

                    proxy: Ext.create('Ext.data.HttpProxy', {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
                        url: 'client.php',
                        noCache: false,
                        startParam: undefined,
                        filterParam: undefined,
                        limitParam: undefined,
                        pageParam: undefined
                    }),

                    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                        root: 'records',
                        id: 'id',
                        fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']
                    }),

                    listeners: {
                        load: function (self, records, successful, eOpts) {
                            var fields = records[0].fields;
                            console.log(fields.getAt(0));
                        }
                    },

                    autoLoad: true
                }),

                flex: '1',
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'first_name' },
                    { text: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'last_name' },
                    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }                        
                ]
            }
```

Comment: What does the server respond? Do you see, in developper tools, the request actually firing and coming back with the response you expect (and a 200 http status code)? ... And I think that what you're trying to debug in your load listener is records[0].data, and not the field.

Comment: Yes. Of course the response is ok.

Comment: I am trying to debug why the data loaded to the store won't show in the grid. And thanks I think you're right about records[0].data

Comment: just a guess but you may have data something like { data: {name: '',... in which case you need to specify a reader off of your proxy and have root: 'data' or something like that

Comment: No. It's not the case

Answer (score 0):

ah.  you have the reader at the wrong level.  It is part of the proxy

```
 proxy: {
    type: "ajax",
    url: "...",  
    reader: {
```